# TypeScript: Easier way to Initialize Nested Objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, object, ecmascript-6

Working in Angular/TypeScript, a small question: Say I have a defined object with nested objects, and a blank constructor. (And in this case, it's from a package so I cannot edit it; otherwise I'd add a constructor.)

Currently I initialize it like this:

```
var childObj = new ChildObj();
childObj.ChildProp = 'my child prop';

var myObj = new MyObj();
myObj.Prop1 = 'foo';
myObj.Prop2 = 'bar';
myObj.ChildProp = childObj;
```

Is there a less cumbersome way of achieving the above? I don't think object initialization syntax works in JS/TypeScript. I'd love to use that kind of syntax:

```
var myObj = new MyObj {
    Prop1 = 'foo',
    Prop2 = 'bar',
    ChildObj = new ChildObj {
        childObj.ChildProp = 'my child prop'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let myObj = {
    prop1: 'foo',
    pop2: 'bar',
    childObj: {
        childProp: 'my child prop'
    }
} as MyObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spreading:

```
var myObj =  { ...(new MyObj()), Prop1: "foo", Prop2: "bar", ChildObj: { ...(new ChidlObj()), ChildProp: "my child prop" } };
```

Comment: Note that this will break the prototype chain, so the methods might be missing.